# iPad self made move animation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit, core-animation

I have a problem with performance on iPad. I need to drag UIView with animation. It's like self made UIScrollView, but with bigger bounce effect.

I use self made animation cycle with NSTimer (scheduletTimerWithInterval 0.3 sec). On each iteration I move view step by step.

But the problem is that it's freeze time to time. Not too much... but enough to feel.. Do anyone knows any approaches to do following thing in correct way, so it will work as charm?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm sure that it's NOT because of algorithm of calculation on each iteration. Because if I move the main view to bottom on about a half of screen size (so only half part of sliding view is visible) it works smoothly. Do anyone knows how standard Core Animation works? Is it something similar inside it (NSTimer)?

Comment: I found one thing - if you will intercept the event touchesMoved and will move some view, you will see that it has bad performance (the view is twitches while moving). But when you doing the same thing in UIScrollView the view moves smoothly. So, how it UIScrollView works inside??

Answer (score 1):

You should use [UIView beginAnimations] instead of the scheduled timer. For example, to move something over 2 seconds, you could do something like this:

```
YourView.center = CGPointMake(0,0);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
YourView.center = CGPointMake(30, 30);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This will move YourView from 0,0 to 30,30 over 2 seconds (that's what the setAnimationDuration is for).  So you would have a sequence of these if you wanted to do a bounce effect. You can also be notified when the animation completed by using

`[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(somefunction)]`

at which point you could kick off another animation in your function "somefunction".

Comment: The problem that I have with this approach is that I should make big number of Animation blocks. Because I have very specific trajectory..

Comment: Dmitry, did you ever solve this? Since my last answer, I discovered UIBezierPath animations, see if that helps you out. Check it out: http://maniacdev.com/2011/01/core-animation-defining-and-following-paths/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the timer causes your problem. The interval of animations should be something like that: 1.0/60.0f